# Getting subtraction wrong in excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-365

This is absurdly simple but I am not getting what I am doing wrong, please help me out.

My formula is very simple:`=V40 - SUM(O40:P40,R40:S40)`

The values of `V40 is 107, O40 is 80, P40 is 0, R40 is 1, S40 is 0`

Ideally the result should be **107 - 81 = 26**, but no matter what I do the result that comes is ***0***

Things that I have tried

1. Changed the format of all the cells to Number format
2. Tried to use Numbervalue on the formula to get correct value, but no result `=NUMBERVALUE(V40)-NUMBERVALUE(SUM(O40:P40,R40:S40))`

PFB the cells in question:
[image]

PFB result in Evaluate Formaula :
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242565/discussion-on-question-by-allwyn-p-getting-subtraction-wrong-in-excel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer or facing the same problem. Do the following things to resolve the issue

1. **If your values are a result of other functions** *check if the formulas for these functions still hold true, if not correct them*
2. **try recreating the same formula in different parts of the worksheet/workbook**, *if the formula works then error is isolated to the cell where you are getting the results*
3. **Try with static values in the formula instead of dynamic, if the problem still pertains then issue is with the cell**
4. ** Check the format of the cell** *Change it to number format*
5. ** Check whether the calculations for the sheet/workbook are set to automatic instead of manual**

These steps should help you isolate the problem to a certain degree
Thanks to **@Rory & @MayukhBhattacharya** for helping me figure out how to sort this issue